# Javascript array losing values after foreach loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to loop though my array and append to an html table. An example of my array looks like this

```
$arrayOne =["text1", "text2", "text3"]
$arrayTwo =["", "mytext1", "mytext1"]
$arrayThree=["dummyText1", "dummyText2", "dummyText3"]
$arrayFour=["fourthText", "Fourth", "Four"]
```

I am looping here

```
arrayOne.forEach(function(value, key){
  let ExampleOne = $arrayOne[key],
      ExampleTwo = $arrayTwo[key] ? $arrayTwo[key] : "",
      ExampleThree = $arrayThree[key] ? $arrayThree[key] : "",
      ExampleFour = $arrayFour[key] ? $arrayFour[key] : "",

    $("#myModal").find("#mysection").append(<tr><td>"+ExampleOne+"</td><td>"+ExampleTwo+"</td><td>"+ExampleThree+"</td><td>"+ExampleFour+"</td>
 }
```

it prints something like

```
text1     ""          "dummytext1"    "fourthText"
test2     ""          "dummyText2"    "Fourth"
text3     "mytext1"   "dummyText3"    "Four"
```

It skips over the contents in the 2nd array. I do not want to get rid of null/empty"" values. I do not want it to skip repeated entries. I am not sure why it is skipping over contents.

Comment: Why are each of the array names prefixed with a `$` inside the loop?  `Foo` and `$Foo` are different symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cleaned up code and ran in JsFiddle and it worked so here you go.

```js
var arrayOne = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];
var arrayTwo = ["", "mytext1", "mytext1"];
var arrayThree = ["dummyText1", "dummyText2", "dummyText3"];
var arrayFour = ["fourthText", "Fourth", "Four"];

arrayOne.forEach(function(value, key) {
    let ExampleOne = arrayOne[key],
        ExampleTwo = arrayTwo[key] ? arrayTwo[key] : "",
        ExampleThree = arrayThree[key] ? arrayThree[key] : "",
        ExampleFour = arrayFour[key] ? arrayFour[key] : "";
      
    $("#myModal").find("#mysection").append("<tr><td>" + ExampleOne + "</td><td>" + ExampleTwo + "</td><td>" + ExampleThree + "</td><td>" + ExampleFour + "</td>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myModal">
  <div id="mysection">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

If you need spaces (which I assume you will) just edit the inline boolean statements you already have.

Comment: Added spaces, removed dollar signs, fixed a lot of syntax issues in the $("#myModal") line. Other than that nothing else.

Comment: I forgot to add the dollar signs in when i asked this question,( see my edit) what syntax issues was in the #myModal line?

Comment: Your quotes are off. You're quoting your Example* arrays when you want to actually quote you "<td>" DOM elements. You also don't have a closing parenthesis.

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answer, please select it as the answer. Thank you!